# Cell2mat for unequal lengths - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've got a simple 2D cell array that contains data in the form of:

[image]

What is the simplest way to be able to use cat/cell2mat when each column can be of an unequal length? Is there a way to replace [] entries with 0?

**EDIT**:

Desired output would be a matrix with the same number of columns. For the example shown above, the rows in the first column would contain:

```
42
58
81
19
84
16
40
60
40
36
```

and so on while the rows of the second column would contain:

```
57
29
14
5
9
69
17
84
12
4
```

and so on.

**EDIT2**:

Adding zeroes would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: what is the result you want to get? do you want 6 matrices (rows) each containing two columns with an unknown number of elements? Why do you need it at all? Because right now you have all your data nicely put together and you can easily loop/address each data

Comment: Can you describe the desired output? Im guessing it's a numerical array but of what size?

Comment: and are those entries in each row of cell array always one dimensional? (I mean is each a column vector?)

Comment: A matrix can't have two columns with unequal lengths

Comment: @ The Minion - see my edit. I need to be able to tally the instances of each recurring number for each column of the cell array. For example - `100` occurs 3 times in the first cell array column. I thought the best would to do this would be to convert it into a matrix and then use `histc` like normal.

Comment: @LuisMendo thats why she said that she wants to replace `[]` with `0`'s i guess.

Comment: @Luis Mendo - yes - this is why i'm asking if it's at all possible to convert the [ ]'s in the cell array into an appropriate number of 0's such that I can then convert it into a matrix.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Where would you enter those zeros? at the end of the column or would you add zeros toeach element of your cell matrix to make those to columns match.

Comment: @TheMinion - at the end would be fine. I essentially just need to add enough zeroes to equal out the lengths to the longest column.

Comment: Added a new almost-vectorized approach to solve this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26777670/3293881), if you would like to take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want. Zeros are added at the end.

```
c = {[1;2] [10; 20; 30]; [3;4;5] [40]; [6; 7] []}; %// example
c1 = vertcat(c{:,1});
c2 = vertcat(c{:,2});
n1 = numel(c1);
n2 = numel(c2);
result = zeros(max(n1,n2),2);
result(1:n1,1) = c1;
result(1:n2,2) = c2;
```

In this example:

```
>> celldisp(c)
c{1,1} =
     1
     2
c{2,1} =
     3
     4
     5
c{3,1} =
     6
     7
c{1,2} =
    10
    20
    30
c{2,2} =
    40
c{3,2} =
     []
>> result
result =
     1    10
     2    20
     3    30
     4    40
     5     0
     6     0
     7     0
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution proposes an almost vectorized approach to solve the stated problem and also makes it a generic one for any number of columns in an input cell array. This is categorized as "almost-vectorized" one because it uses `cellfun('length'..)` (if you look at the code) and AFAIK `cellfun` is basically a wrapper to a for-loop. But in this case, `cellfun('length'..)` is very lightweight and rest of the code is vectorized and that's why the term "almost-vectorized".

Code -

```
%// 3 column sized input cell array
c = {[1;2] [10; 20; 30] [3;8;42]; [3;4;5] [40] [3]; [6; 7] [] [5;9;11;32]} 

lens = sum(cellfun('length',c),1)
out = zeros(max(lens),numel(lens))
out(bsxfun(@le,[1:max(lens)]',lens)) = vertcat(c{:})
```

Output -

```
>> c
c = 
    [2x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]
    [3x1 double]    [        40]    [         3]
    [2x1 double]              []    [4x1 double]
>> out
out =
     1    10     3
     2    20     8
     3    30    42
     4    40     3
     5     0     5
     6     0     9
     7     0    11
     0     0    32
```

Answer (score 0):

I would urge you to take a look at `cellfun`. My solution below would work really well, were it not for the `'UniformOutput', false`-part. This is only necessary because some cells in my example are empty matrices, on which `histc` behaves differently.

```
cellarray = cell(3,2);
cellarray(:,1)= {[3, 2, 1]; [12, 3, 4, 6]; []};

edges = 1:13; % If you do not know the range of values, find them using cellfun(min, cellarray), and max
x = cellfun(@(x)histc(x, edges), cellarray, 'UniformOutput', false)
```